# thinking sphinx search model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

this is a real noob question but I'm having trouble finding a clear response in the doc:

Is it possible to use Thinking Sphinx to search through a model object's associations.

EXAMPLE:

```
@user.posts.search("I'm confused")
```

All the examples I see would involve searching User.

Comment: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx checkout usage

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to search through a model object's associations like in example indexes are created against uploads model association.

define_index do
    indexes title
    indexes description
    indexes uploads.file_file_name, :as => :upload_file_name
    indexes uploads.file_content_type, :as => :upload_file_content_type

```
has :id
has price
has user_id
has created_at
has purchase_count
has images.photo_file_size
has tags.id, :as => :tag_id, :facet => true
has tags.parent_id, :as => :tag_parent_id, :facet => true
has "state='active'", :as => :active, :type => :boolean, :facet => true
has "count(images.id) > 0", :as => :has_image, :type => :boolean
has "sum(uploads.file_file_size)", :as => :total_size, :type => :integer
```

end